# compare TypedDependencies from Stanford NLP dependency parser tree

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, text-mining

I am trying a semantic match between two sentences by comparing the dependencies.
I am getting two Stanford dependency trees from two different sentences. I want to compare and get a score for the semantic match between the sentences.

```
for(TypedDependency td1 : dependencyList1)
    {
        for(TypedDependency td2 : dependencyList2)
        {
            score = td1.compareTo(td2);
        }
    }
```

`dependencyList1` and `dependencyList2` are the list of all dependencies from sentences1 and sentence 2 respectively.
  I am using a `compareTo` function which gives out scores of `-1,0,1`.
I then average out the scores to come up with a final score.
I don't know how these scores are calculated.
 Is there a better way to compare and identify similar dependencies.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`compareTo()` gives you an ordering between dependencies, e.g., for sorting (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). To find similar dependencies, you first need to formalize exactly what you mean by "similar", and then make a custom scoring function.

A natural metric, beyond simple equality, is collapsing things like `*subj` (nsubj, nsubjpass, csubj, csubjpass) and `*obj` (dobj, iobj). If you care about the endpoints of the arcs, checking for lemma match rather than word match is maybe a good start. Similarity in vector space (e.g., with word2vec or GloVE) is also quite effective.

The list of dependencies, for reference, can be found at: http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/u/dep/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. In 'similar' I meant to find the exact dependency i.e.   the governor word, the dependent word and  the relation between them should match. I will create a custom scoring function.